# Rails - ActiveModel::Serializer virtual attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-model-serializers

I'm using the active_model_serializers gem for a RoR API. Versions:

**Rails:** 4.2.8

**Ruby:** 2.2.5

**active_model_serializers:** 0.10.0

I'm using a virtual attribute in a serializer. I get it by using a sub query when I retrieve the objects from the database.

You can find the code here: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/LuisDeHaro/ebf92781b449aa1ee7b85f8f552dd672)

This is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method 'number_of_reservations' for DiscountSchedule...
```

This field isn't defined in the table nor in the model (attr_accessor)

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, I have a very similar serializer and it's working OK.

Any help will be appreciated.

*EDIT:*

I have another serializer where the virtual/calculated field is working OK. My guess on this is that since AR is making a bunch of LEFT OUTER JOINS and the SELECT list of the query is very big at some point something is getting broke.

Comment: Can you also share the code of the serializer and also your controller.

Comment: Why truncate the error? Show full error and stack trace if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The link won't work for me as I don't have access at my work place, however, from the error I can recommend you to check if you have defined the attributes like this in your serializer `attributes :number_of_reservations` and have an action in the serializer that says

```
def number_of_reservations
  // Your logic goes here.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this question has to be about ActiveRecord, rather than AMS. You're trying to use `select` and alias to collect some computed (aggregate) attribute along with objects themselves. This, unfortunately, won't work in ActiveRecord, at least not in versions below 4.2.X. And this is why you're observing this behavior, there is no `number_of_reservations` in your models.

To see what's going on, try to inspect `@objects` here: https://gist.github.com/LuisDeHaro/ebf92781b449aa1ee7b85f8f552dd672#file-some_controller-rb-L17

Comment: That's right, there's no 'number_of_reservations' property in the objects. However for some reason this is working in another serializer I have. But you might be right, the culprit may be AR. I have updated my Q.

Comment: Could you show that working serializer and accompanying query? What I'm trying to say is that serializer library (if it's properly engineered and decoupled with ORM) knows nothing about how you get your data, it just calls methods (attributes). And the second statement (most important) is that AR cannot add aggregate attributes to objects (which is something that Ecto does easily, for example). What you can do is to run two queries, one to get objects you want, then in second one only select your computed attributes, then populate attributes on your models with `.each` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed: the issue was by the big amount of LEFT JOINS that the includes(:table_name) is generating. The serializer then does not know what to do.

I found a monkey-patch gem that works for AR (Rails 4 & 5) that fix this.

https://github.com/alekseyl/rails_select_on_includes

So, the virtual field number_of_reservations is picked up by the serializer like a charm.

And, you might be wondering: why do you want to retrieve a field that is not in the table definition in the database. A: well, in some scenarios you will need a calculated field for EVERY row you are retrieving. A SQL sub query is one of the most efficient ways to do so.

It's working now for me.